# Product images distorted/too large in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm running WooCommerce on WordPress and I'm currently trying to batch upload images using the CSV import feature. The problem is that my images have rectangular dimensions (they are vertically aligned) so the generated thumbnail for the product page shows a square-shaped portion of the middle of the image (see screenshot).

[image: screenshot]

And the original image:

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way for me to set it so that WordPress will keep the proportions fixed when generating a thumbnail so that there will be no distortion?

Also, this does not seem to be related to the image thumbnail settings found on the WooCommerce > General Settings page where the dimensions of the thumbnails can be set. I have updated these to reflect the dimensions of the images used in the theme so it seems the issue I'm having lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things you need to know about image dimensions in WooCommerce is that many themes (and the default WooCommerce CSS) specify product image widths to ensure consistent layouts across multiple devices.

The dimensions you specify on the Products tab of the WooCommerce settings screen affect the size of the thumbnails that the theme uses when displaying product images. They do not change the size the image is rendered.

When this happens, there is a possibility that your settings may not be adequate (too small) for your theme – which can cause image distortion (blurriness). 
**Visit to the following link to get the full answer** - > http://docs.woothemes.com/document/using-the-appropriate-product-image-dimensions/

Answer (score 0):

Use [Square Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/square-thumbnails/) plugin that hooks on thumbnails (re)generation. Set it up, for example to add white space and center image vertically and horizontally. It keeps aspect ratio and doesn't crop image. Then invoke thumbnails regeneration. It can be done with [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin.